# ReactJS + Chrome extension: Add background.js to build folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a chrome extension with React.js. Right now, I'm testing my extension by running `yarn build` and then dragging the `build` folder into my chrome homepage and clicking on the extension to see the changes.

However, I'm having a problem where I can't create a `background.js` file in the `build` folder in order to test some background events I need to respond to in my extension. The relevant `package.json` code is

```
"background": {
  "scripts": ["static/background.js"],
  "persistent": false
},
```

I'm getting an error because `static/background.js` doesn't exist in my `static/` folder after building. Is there any way to have the `background.js` script appear in the build each time I run it, besides just copying the file in each time I run `yarn build`? Alternativley, is there a better way to test my react app as a chrome extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A background.js file is not necessary to configure a ReactJS project as a chrome extension.

The best resource I used to build a ReactJS project as a chrome extension was a medium article by Hu.Chen: 
https://link.medium.com/6DohXDpmaV

Important note: this extension configures your ReactJS application to render in a Chrome new tab.

Good luck! Hope this helps!

Comment: You don't "need" a background.js folder, but is there a better way to perform background tasks with a react chrome extension?

Comment: I do believe background.js is produced in the build. When I run “npm run build” as described in the medium post, background.js is placed in the static folder of build.

Answer (score 0):

You can use background and content files in react chrome extension. Here is the [medium article](https://medium.com/litslink/how-to-create-google-chrome-extension-using-react-js-5c9e343323ff) on how to implement it.